# Creating a loop for images in a lightbox

Tags: javascript, php, lightbox

I want to implement a lightbox on a website that shows 83 images, I am not going to copy paste all of them in HTML, so I want them in a loop with PHP.

They already work on another page, so I copied that code but I can't get it to work.

What I got in the working code:

```
<a href="images/project1.jpg" rel="lightbox[slides]"><img src="images/project1.jpg" border=0></a><!--class="spacing"-->
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
    <?
        $dirname = 'afbeeldingen/slides/exhaustion_pipe/';
        $images = scandir($dirname);
        $ignore = Array(".", "..");

        foreach($images as $curimg){
            if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
                echo '<a href="'.$dirname.$curimg.'" rel="lightbox[slides]"><img src="'.$dirname.$curimg.'" width="1" height="1" border="0"></a>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Now I tried to copy and edit it to this:

```
<a href="afbeeldingen/slides/dias/Dia1.JPG" rel="lightbox[slides]">Bla</a><!--class="spacing"-->
    <div style="visibility: hidden;">
        <?
            $dirname = 'afbeeldingen/slides/dias/';
            $images = scandir($dirname);
            $ignore = Array(".", "..");

            foreach($images as $curimg){
                if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
                    echo '<a href="'.$dirname.$curimg.'" rel="lightbox[slides]"><img src="'.$dirname.$curimg.'" width="1" height="1" border="0"></a>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

I got rid of the image and changed it into text, because I don't have the correct image yet.

When I click the text it shows me Dia1.JPG in a new window, but I want the first image to open in the lightbox from which you can navigate to other images.

If it helps, this is the lightbox.js: http://rvs.werkvreugde.nl/slider_scripts/lightbox.js

I hope I provided enough resources to see what I mean.

Does anybody know how to loop the 83 images through the lightbox? The images are called Dia1 - Dia83

Thanks!

Comment: you snippet is fine, can you please check your css file lightbox.css is properly included into your html page?

Comment: Yes, lightbox.css is included in top_new.php (the header), this is how I added it: <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: i don't exactly know your folder hierarchy href="" of lightbox.css should be according to the folder you placed file in. and one thing more try to use <link rel="stylesheet" href="directory/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> into <head> include css file here </head> section of html.

Comment: I already got the css file included in the head section. So I don't know what could be causing it, looks like the JS doesn't get loaded somehow.